# Native vs Framework development for simple board game development

Tags: android, libgdx, board-game

I have been working on a simple word game like `Hangman Pro` but for a different `language` and I have been using `libgdx` blindly. After a lot of hassle and unnecessary distractions, I am beginning to wonder if it is an overkill to use the library to do such a simple game. So my question is, is it possible or even professional to do such a game with just the native `android` libraries ? Will that be an uphill battle in itself.

P.S. I am not an `android` newbiew but am not a professional either. It is a hobby thing.

Comment: Libgdx on android is native, it just uses a native [lib](https://i.gyazo.com/842fdc628d2033f44bfc5c9904ba73b7.png)

Comment: yeah but still it has a learning curve to it that i would rather not deal with if I am working on a simple game that doesn't involve fancy graphics and physics libraries.

Comment: You simply use a spritebatch and render textures on the screen (you should also use a camera to make your life easier). So, what learning curve ? Its really just java code. I don't use physics libraries either, because I don't need them. Don't use something, unless you *have to* (like the rendering part, or playing sound, for example).

Comment: `result/speed = profesionalism` anything goes. If the Libgdx framework has classes that help you out a great deal then go for it. If you already know how to create what you want without a framework and learning the framework takes more time then don't. I personally do anything game related with LibGDX and if I ever make a simple app that only needs basic views/screens I consider dropping the framework.

Comment: great help guys. have decided to drop libgdx for this case. but i don't think this is the last game i will make. so who knows ?